# EC2 Windows instance clocks up to 200 milliseconds apart, despite Amazon Time Sync

Tags: amazon-ec2, ntp

I am running this AMI

```
Microsoft Windows Server 2019 Base - ami-06d94a49607efea43
Microsoft Windows 2019 Datacenter edition. [English]
```

on 3 instances in the same region (Tokyo). 2 instances are in the same AZ, one is in a different AZ.

All of the instances synchronize with the [Amazon Time Sync Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/windows-set-time.html):

```
C:>w32tm /query /configuration | findstr 169
NtpServer: 169.254.169.123 (Local)
```

However, I have seen the time difference between the machines diverge up to 200 milliseconds.

Can this be kept below 1 millisecond?

Answer (score 0):

I just tried

```
w32tm /resync
```

on all 3 machines to manually sync them, and since then, the lag fluctuates in a band of 2-3ms, and sometimes diverges up to 4-5ms, which is a huge improvement. Let's hope it stays that way.